# Does it make sense to learn any other language except English, being a mathematician?

Tags: soft-question, career-development

Would it be an advantage for a committed modern day research mathematicians to learn any foreign language? Are there works in Russian, French, or any other foreign language being produced or that have not been translated?

Comment: It's going to be an advantage, it can't hurt, but the question is how small.

Comment: Don't assume that everybody here is in the same country.  For many of us, languages other than English are not necessarily "foreign".

Comment: I wondered this as well. Now I'm trying to translate a paper in Russian via Google translate. It's not an easy task.

Comment: I seem to remember technical competence in French, German, or Russian (as well as English) being a requirement of Waterloo's doctorate program at the mathematics faculty. By "technical competence" I mean being able to understand a paper with the aid of a dictionary. So in some places the extra language would be a requirement to be a mathematician in the first place.

Comment: I would even go so far as to say that Latin could be useful.

Comment: Regarding "being a mathematicians" [sic]:  It is a good idea to learn one language (such as English) really well.

Answer (score 12):

From what I understand, a *ton* of [Alexander Grothendieck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alexander_Grothendieck)'s work in algebraic geometry has not been translated from its original French.  See, for example, [Éléments de Géométrie Algébrique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89l%C3%A9ments_de_g%C3%A9om%C3%A9trie_alg%C3%A9brique) and [Fondements de la Géometrie Algébrique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fondements_de_la_G%C3%A9ometrie_Alg%C3%A9brique).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there are many such works. These days, less French than Russian, but still a decent chunk of both.

Comment: Do you mind new works, or historical relevant works? Could you point to some concrete examples? (no matter what language)

Comment: @Howard Langtone consider Gelfond, Calculus of finite differences (1959). http://inis.jinr.ru/sl/vol1/UH/_Ready/Mathematics/Gel%27fond%20A.%20Ischislenie%20konechnyh%20raznostej%20%281959%29%28ru%29%28L%29%28201s%29.pdf It has been translated to English only in 1971 in India. It is the only book where I found criteria of possibility to represent an analytic function as Newton series.

Comment: Many past works have not been translated.  Unlike some fields (like physics or medicine), work from many years ago is still sometimes valuable for the mathematics researcher.

Answer (score 2):

For a lot of algebraic stuff you'll need at least a little French. Note that being good enough at a language to read a math paper with the aid of a dictionary is wildly less than the amount you need to have a conversation, so it's not asking too much for someone to pick up this ability in a few languages. Just sit down and practice through some papers where you're already comfortable with the math (say, a textbook in a subject you know very well) and you will be fine, although it will take some patience and hopefully a friend who speaks the language well.

Answer (score 2):

> Would it be an advantage for a committed modern day research
>   mathematicians to learn any foreign language?

Knowing other languages and cultures (other than your native one) can make one a more interesting person which will certainly help during the job search phase and in general academic life.